# Enter password for encrypted Windows disc after GRUB

Tags: multi-boot, grub, uefi, veracrypt

I'm using dualboot setup with Windows 10 (with enabled Bitlocker) and Debian 9 (with encrypted LVM). Both systems have own disc. I'm not much confident about Bitlocker, so I would like to use VeraCrypt to encrypt Windows disc.

So I have a question. If I will encrypt Windows disc with VeraCrypt, is it possible to enter the password AFTER I will select to boot Windows in GRUB? So first thing on monitor will be GRUB, where I select Debian or Windows. And if I select Windows, then I will be ask to enter VeraCrypt password. Is this possible?

PS I'm using UEFI with disabled SecureBoot